# Xcode not XCode in 2018 Dev survey

Tags: bug, status-completed, survey-2018

In the developer survey 2018 post, `Xcode` was referred as `XCode`.
(https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2018/)

Check this link.

https://developer.apple.com/xcode/

Comment: IIRC Xcode has been mis-capitalized in previous years as well.

Comment: Next year: X/Code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is now fixed; thanks so much for the heads up.